# GeoServer generated Image Mosaic properties missing TimeAttribute

Tags: postgis, geoserver, geoserver-rest-api, image-mosaic

I am using an ImageMosaic store with a granule index stored in a PostgreSQL database. Adding granules and updating the index is done manually and not through GeoServer. GeoServer is accessing the index through a view (`uoi_rain_v` as in `datastore.properties` `TypeName`

To configure the store I am using the following files:

- `datastore.properties`

  ```
  SPI=org.geotools.data.postgis.PostgisNGDataStoreFactory
  host=...
  port=...
  database=...
  schema=public
  user=...
  passwd=...
  Loose\ bbox=true
  Estimated\ extends=false
  validate\ connections=true
  Connection\ timeout=10
  preparedStatements=true
  ```
- `indexer.properties`

  ```
  Schema=*the_geom:Polygon,location:String,ingestion:java.util.Date
  Name=rain
  TypeName=uoi_rain_v
  TimeAttribute=ingestion
  AbsolutePath=true
  Caching=false
  Recursive=false
  CanBeEmpty=true
  UseExistingSchema=true
  ```
- `Coverage.xml`

  ```
  <coverage>
      <nativeCoverageName>rain</nativeCoverageName>
      <name>rain</name>
  </coverage>
  ```
- `CoverageDimension.xml`

  ```
  <coverage>
      <name>rain</name>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
      <metadata>
          <entry key="time">
              <dimensionInfo>
                  <enabled>true</enabled>
                  <presentation>LIST</presentation>
                  <units>ISO8601</units>
                  <defaultValue>
                      <strategy>MINIMUM</strategy>
                  </defaultValue>
              </dimensionInfo>
          </entry>
      </metadata>
  </coverage>
  ```

The steps I am following are these:

1. I create an empty ImageMosaic store using a zip file that contains `datastore.properties` and `indexer.properties`

   ```
   curl -u admin:geoserver -XPUT -H "Content-type:application/zip" --data-binary @test.zip http://proxy/geoserver/rest/workspaces/uoi/coveragestores/rain/file.imagemosaic?configure=none
   ```

   The store is created and also the two configuration files are copied in `geoserver_data/data/uoi/rain/` directory.
2. I configure a coverage by

   ```
   curl -v -u admin:geoseerver -XPOST -H "Content-type: text/xml" -d @Coverage.xml http://proxy/geoserver/rest/workspaces/uoi/coveragestores/rain/coverages
   ```

   After this step, two new files are created at `geoserver_data/data/uoi/rain/`:

   - `sample_image.dat`
   - `rain.properties`

     ```
     ExpandToRGB=false
     TypeName=uoi_rain_v
     SuggestedFormat=org.geotools.gce.geotiff.GeoTiffFormat
     Name=rain
     SuggestedSPI=it.geosolutions.imageioimpl.plugins.tiff.TIFFImageReaderSpi
     LevelsNum=1
     PathType=ABSOLUTE
     Heterogeneous=false
     Caching=false
     HeterogeneousCRS=false
     LocationAttribute=location
     Levels=0.01,0.0125
     CheckAuxiliaryMetadata=false
     MosaicCRS=EPSG\:4326
     ```

   The problem is that the generated `rain.properties` is missing `TimeAttribute`, even though it is defined in `indexer.properties`.
3. I also tried updating the dimensions of the coverage but `TimeAttribute` is still missing from `rain.properties`

   ```
   curl -v -u admin:password -XPUT -H "Content-type: text/xml" -d @CoverageDimension http://proxy/geoserver/rest/workspaces/uoi/coveragestores/rain/coverages/rain
   ```

If I manually edit the file to include `TimeAttribute`, I can then proceed setting up the coverage with no issues.

I am using GeoServer 2.21.1

I followed the tutorials in these links:

- https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/imagemosaic.html#uploading-an-empty-mosaic
- https://docs.geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/multidim/rest/index.html#configuring-an-empty-mosaic
- https://doc-geonode.readthedocs.io/en/latest/005_dev_workshop/006_geonode_apis/geoserver_rest/examples/curl.html#creating-an-empty-mosaic-and-harvest-granules

Comment: so far i created time-based mosaic stores only with a file `timeregex.properties`
is there a reason you are not doing that?

Comment: Yes, I need to be able to manage the index without messing with the actual files. I can easily alter the result of the View, and the available granules as a consequence. In any case it is a valid use. I am just wondering if I am doing something wrong or it is a bug. For now I manually edit the generated file as part of the coverage creation operation, but this is not ideal.

Comment: You can consider writing on the GeoServer mailing list https://sourceforge.net/projects/geoserver/lists/geoserver-users